# Dialog: confirmation when dismissed

Tags: android, dialog, listener

Topic: I want to be able to cancel a dismiss call on a dialog.

I am entering information thorugh a dialog. When data inside the dialog has changed and the user dismisses the dialog without saving (by pressing back or clicking outside of the dialog), I want to be able to prevent that dismis by showing a confirmation dialog, that asks the user if he really wants do dismiss the dialog.
An analagy for what I am looking for is in VBA, where the cancel-variable of a beforeSave-listener can be set to "true", so that the file is not saved, even though save is pressed.

I could not find a solution that I can place inside the dismissListener of the dialog.

Thanks a lot in advance and best regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can maintain the state of dialog open/ close in a boolean and handle it. When you open the dialog you make it true and when user clicks back or outside the dialog check that boolean and show the alert pop-up and when dialog closes (dismisses) make boolean to false.

Comment: Hello Raj, I am not quite sure how this will work. Do you mean that I should reopen the dialog, when the boolean is a certain value?

Comment: Can you explain me how the content inside dialog you will be changing and saving in normal case? You will be placing edit text and button in dialog?

Comment: Hello Raj, exactly. I have a list view, and I open the individual elements of that list view with a dialog. The information of that item can be changed with the dialog.

Comment: alert.setCancelable(false); // where alert is instance of AlertDialog.Builder - you can use this to disable dialog close when clicking outside the dialog. As already mentioned in order to handle back press you must maintain a boolean when dialog open and close so that when back pressed onBackPressed() override method will be called where you can check boolean show a toast message if you need.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. Is there a way to do something similar, when a click occurs outside of the dialog?

Comment: dialog.setOnCancelListener(
        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                //When you touch outside of dialog bounds  
                // Here you can use that Boolean I already mentioned and handle
            }
        }
);

Answer (score 0):

user these methods on your dialog view to prevent cancel dialog

```
 ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
 progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
 progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
 progressDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, this is not what I am looking for. I want to be able to dismiss the dialog when clicking outside of the dialog, when no infarmation hast changed, so disabling it overall is not an option.